# Is there a way to know how far R has gotten on a random forest model?

Tags: r, random-forest, diagnostics

I am currently learning about random forests and how to create them in R. However as I have discovered, it can be quite the time consuming activity creating these trees, and sometimes I do not know how far R has gotten or if it has crashed, and so I close R in panic. I use the randomForest package, and my code is as follows:

```
model <- randomForest(def ~ ., 
                      data = mydataset, 
                      mtry = 4, 
                      ntree = 200, 
                      importance = TRUE)
```

Is there a way to make R show me how far it has gotten at any time, or when it is finished with one tree and is continuing to the next?

Comment: See my answer to make the output more verbose. If you find `randomForest` too slow, you may want to look into the `ranger` package which I found trained random forests much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situation such as these, you are typically looking for an argument that makes the function more verbose. This is typically something like `verbose = TRUE` but it varies and some functions do not offer any kind of verbosity settings.

In your case, you just have to look up the help of `randomForest` (with `?randomForest::randomForest`) to find the argument `do.trace`.

> do.trace
>   If set to TRUE, give a more verbose output as randomForest is run. If set to some integer, then running output is printed for every do.trace trees.

In other words, you can enable verbosity with:

```
model <- randomForest(def ~ ., data = mydataset, mtry = 4, 
                      ntree = 200, importance = TRUE, do.trace = TRUE)
```

or, to print some feedback every 100 trees:

```
model <- randomForest(def ~ ., data = mydataset, mtry = 4, 
                      ntree = 200, importance = TRUE, do.trace = 100)
```

It is always a good reflex to check the manual of the function as a first step. If you use rstudio, you can use the `help` pane instead of using `?` or `??`.